# How to make a random image generator that creates 2 images

Tags: javascript, html

Hi my friend and I are doing a high school project and we are just making a basic website for it. We are trying to make a random image generator that creates 2 images but we don't know JS very well and have this so far from finding things online. It creates one image but I want to know how to make it display 2 at a time, thank you from a new coder.

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">

 function displayRandomImages()   
{  
   
   var imageArray = [  
   {   
      
     src: "https://www.activewild.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Cheetah-Fastest-Animal-On-Land.jpg" ,  
       
     width: "280",  
     height: "200"  
   },   
   {  
     src: "https://www.mowdirect.co.uk/media/catalog/product/s/p/sp533_.jpg" ,  
     width: "320",  
     height: "195"  
   },   
   {  
     src: "https://www.rolab.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/r1.pink_.hoverboard.jpg",  
     width: "320",  
     height: "195"  
   },  
   {  
     src: "https://seanscottphotography.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/2927.jpg",  
     width: "350",  
     height: "250" 

     
     
    }   ];  
       
    var arrayLength = imageArray.length;  
    var newArray = [];  
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {  
        newArray[i] = new Image();  
        newArray[i].src = imageArray[i].src;  
        newArray[i].width = imageArray[i].width;  
        newArray[i].height = imageArray[i].height;  
    }  
     
  function getRandomNum(min, max)   
  {  
      imgNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
      return newArray[imgNo];  
  }    
   
  var newImage = getRandomNum(0, newArray.length - 1);  
   
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');  
  var l = images.length;  
  for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {  
     images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);  
  }  
   
  document.body.appendChild(newImage);  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: ‘setInterval’ call function periodically

Comment: The description of your problem and your code does not match. You are talking about creating images using an image generator, implying new images will be made, but the code indicates you are making an image viewer that randomly chooses and display images from an existing set of images, no? I'd suggest you clean up your description so that people understand what it is you're actually trying to do, and then hopefully you'll get some good answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You got it quite solid.. so solid that all I did was make a second image with your own functions.. it would take out all the images so that there isn't an overlap.. good work.. I just used an interval through method `setInterval` and it was smooth sailing

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function displayRandomImages()   
{  
   var displayRate=3000 //images would switch every 3 seconds.. u can change this number
   var imageArray = [  
   {   
      
     src: "https://www.activewild.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Cheetah-Fastest-Animal-On-Land.jpg" ,  
       
     width: "280",  
     height: "200"  
   },   
   {  
     src: "https://www.mowdirect.co.uk/media/catalog/product/s/p/sp533_.jpg" ,  
     width: "320",  
     height: "195"  
   },   
   {  
     src: "https://www.rolab.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/r1.pink_.hoverboard.jpg",  
     width: "320",  
     height: "195"  
   },  
   {  
     src: "https://seanscottphotography.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/2927.jpg",  
     width: "350",  
     height: "250" 

     
     
    }   ];  
       
    var arrayLength = imageArray.length;  
    var newArray = [];  
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {  
        newArray[i] = new Image();  
        newArray[i].src = imageArray[i].src;  
        newArray[i].width = imageArray[i].width;  
        newArray[i].height = imageArray[i].height;  
    }  
     
  function getRandomNum(min, max)   
  {  
      imgNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
      return newArray[imgNo];  
  }    
  var interval=setInterval(function(){ 
    var newImage = getRandomNum(0, newArray.length - 1);  
    var newImage2 = getRandomNum(0, newArray.length - 1);  

    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');  
    var l = images.length;  
    for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {  
       images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);  
    }  
   
    document.body.appendChild(newImage);  
    document.body.appendChild(newImage2);
  },displayRate)
}  
</script>
```